# Creating an array sorting function that ensures like values aren't adjacent

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects with a `type` property; there are 5 possible 'types'. Importantly, the elements are inserted into the array and the randomness should be preserved as much as possible; it's only 3rd-party software constraint that's forcing this non-adjacency business.

I want to sort that array so that no adjacent values are alike, or, if this proves impossible, to ensure that the unsortable pairs arrive at the bottom.

I've tried this:

```
function check_adjacency($obj_1, $obj_2) {
    return $obj_1->type == $obj_2->type ? 0 : 1;  // also tried -1
}
usort($arr, "check_adjacency");
```

I can sort of see why this doesn't work; there's no criterion for returning 1 vs -1. But I'm stumped on how to (effectively) write this in PHP. I also tried writing my own function to achieve this but I keep ending up completing too early or with infinite loops. Strategic advice as much as solutions both welcome.

**Update**

Following requests for an example:

I've used sequential variable names for convenience, but in fact the objects are added to the array in a random order with regard to their `type` property.

```
$objs = [ $obj_1, $obj_2, $obj_3, $obj_$4... $obj_300];
foreach($objs as $o) print $o->type
```

Yields:

```
>> "t2", "t1", "t1", "t2", "t2", "t4", "t3", "t3", "t3", "t5", "t1", "t2"...
```

Ideally, after sorting, something like this would obtain.

```
>> "t2", "t1", "t2", "t4", "t3", "t1", "t3", "t2", "t3", "t5", "t1", "t2"
```

Basically, if the next element in the set has the same `type` property as the one preceding it, remove it and insert at the earliest index thereafter. Let me know if this hasn't clarified things.

**Edit The 2nd:**

Thought of a simpler way to explain this. I have a whole lot of books—small books, medium books, and large books. All have different titles; I want a bookshelf on which no two books of the same size sit beside one and other, and which are otherwise randomly distributed.

Comment: it would be much better if you have shown `$obj_1, $obj_2` contents and the final expected result

Comment: what is your actual input and expected output?

Comment: I don't think this can be done with `usort`. The comparison function only gets the values, it doesn't know anything about where they are in the array. And even if it looks in the array, that just gets their original positions, not where they've been moved to by sorting. And elements can keep moving around during the sorting process.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @Anant Does that help?

Comment: Would it be more accurate to say you want a **shuffler** rather than a sorter that will not allow any identical items to be directly next to one-another? Your edit of `and which are otherwise randomly distributed.` seems to suggest that you want a shuffler.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus That's exactly correct; my apologies, I wasn't aware of this phrase. The fact that the objects are already random also left me blind to explaining this constraint until Barmar's solution turned up. I've marked his answer as correct as since it really did answer my initial question and am trying to modify it to my real needs now; it's sort of working except that it's taking an extremely long time and sometimes PHP is running out of memory!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in two steps. First create a 2-dimensional array whose keys are the `type` properties, and elements are an array of all the items with that type. Then loop through these keys, removing one item from each group and adding it to the result array.

```
// step 1
$arr_by_type = array();
foreach ($arr as $el) {
    if (isset($arr_by_type[$el->type])) {
        $arr_by_type[$el->type][] = $el;
    } else {
        $arr_by_type[$el->type] = array($el);
    }
}

// step 2
$result = array();
while (!empty($arr_by_type)) {
    foreach ($arr_by_type as $type => &$sub_array) {
        $result[] = array_pop($sub_array);
        if (empty($sub_array)) {
            unset($result[$type]);
        }
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: I see where you're headed with this; my context makes this unfeasible, though if I understand it maybe I can reproduce it. Each element in the array is almost certainly going to be unique; they're objects with a variety of properties, so `array_count_values()` will just give me a list of keys with 1 as their value. The only thing I'm concerned with is the `type` property of each object. 

I could imagine writing a function to count how many elements sharing each `type` exist, and storing their indices to achieve this... I am a designer, not a developer haha... does that sound reasonable?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that. I've changed the answer to group by the type, not just count items.

Comment: Thanks for the effort so far; there are quite a few typos here, haha; I can see the intention, fine, all the same, except for the missing argument in `array_unshift`. This code is a bit over my head so I'm not sure what you intended there?

Comment: Oops, that was supposed to be `array_shift`. It removes the first item from the array, and returns it.

Comment: Ack. Actually, looking at this more closely—and I apologize, I didn't clarify this in my question—this will, I think, give me an orderly sequence of the various `types`. The context, here, is for cognitive science; ideally, a *completely* random order is desired, but, we have a 3rd-party software constraint whereby adjacent and like objects throw an error, and so these have to be removed whilst preserving as much randomness as possible. Sorry : S

Comment: I changed it to `array_pop`, which is a little more efficient. I had something different in an earlier edit that made `array_shift` more appropriate.

Comment: You can use `array_rand()` to select an element of an array randomly. But then you'll need to use a loop that checks if you duplicate the previous type and try again. I'll leave that as an exercise for you, there's only so much of your work that I'm willing to do for you. If you're not a programmer and you need one, you need to get one, you can't just expect randoms on the Internet to do all your work for you.

Comment: Ahh, nice; this I can do. Thanks!